# Getting LOCATE to return to variable SQL DB2

Tags: sql, if-statement, db2, locate

is it possible to use

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(IN QUERYSTRING VARCHAR(128))
 LANGUAGE SQL
 BEGIN
 DECLARE switch integer default 0;
 set switch = LOCATE('select', querystring,1);
 IF switch <> 0 then
 .......
 ELSE
 .......
 END IF;
 END@
```

the querystring could be 'select count(*) from testtag' OR 'insert into testtab'

Any ideas if I could do this and how to get the LOCATE return value into the variable?

Windows DB2 10.5

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the LOCATE will return either 0 or the relevant offset. Be clear about the functionality however, especially for 'insert into...(select ...from)'.

Comment: When I try to use the above source it doesn't set the switch variable. Is there something that I forgot, or do you have to to it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, compare its output on your environment:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
set serveroutput on@
update command options using s on@

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE locateTEST(IN QUERYSTRING VARCHAR(128))
 LANGUAGE SQL
 specific locatetest
 BEGIN
     DECLARE switch integer default 0;
     set switch = LOCATE('select', querystring,1);
     IF switch <> 0 then
       call dbms_output.put_line('Switch: '||varchar(switch));
    ELSE
       call dbms_output.put_line('Switch: 0');
    END IF;
END@

call locatetest('    insert into fred(mycol) values(1)')@
call locatetest('    select count(*) from testtag')@
```

The above gives the following output if executed from the Db2 command line (e.g. on windows from the db2cmd.exe window with an already existing connection to the database):

```
set serveroutput on
DB20000I  The SET SERVEROUTPUT command completed successfully.

update command options using s on
DB20000I  The UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS command completed successfully.

CREATE or replace PROCEDURE locateTEST(IN QUERYSTRING VARCHAR(128))
 LANGUAGE SQL
 specific locatetest
 BEGIN
     DECLARE switch integer default 0;
     set switch = LOCATE('select', querystring,1);
     IF switch <> 0 then
       call dbms_output.put_line('Switch: '||varchar(switch));
    ELSE
       call dbms_output.put_line('Switch: 0');
    END IF;
END
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

call locatetest('    insert into fred(mycol) values(1)')

  Return Status = 0

Switch: 0

call locatetest('    select count(*) from testtag')

  Return Status = 0

Switch: 5
```

Comment: It works thank you, I noticed that I checked the wrong query sting variable.... but the dbms.output part I did not know. So that is a future great help too.

Comment: would you happen to know how to get the error message from the sqlcode? Like the text that is includes with the code

Comment: That seems a different question, not appropriate for a comment. Refer to GET DIAGNOSTICS.

Comment: Found a way with that. Thanks